# How to detect onClick on png image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a png image with transparent background.

**Goal:** implement `OncLickListener` only to the actual image bounds. (not the `View` bounds).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please post the XML layout code for this PNG image and background

Comment: You would have to override onTouchEvent, get where the user clicked, retrieve the pixel in that spot and verify if that spot is part of the background.